# Failed to start apache

Tags: server, apache2

I am getting the following error when I am trying to start apache. Reinstalling apache isn't helping.

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-06-19 18:24:57 +06; 4ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 14588 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 19 18:24:57 bappy-desktop apache2[14588]:  *
Jun 19 18:24:57 bappy-desktop apache2[14588]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Jun 19 18:24:57 bappy-desktop apache2[14588]: Output of config test was:
Jun 19 18:24:57 bappy-desktop apache2[14588]: apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:...tory
Jun 19 18:24:57 bappy-desktop apache2[14588]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Jun 19 18:24:57 bappy-desktop apache2[14588]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jun 19 18:24:57 bappy-desktop systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 19 18:24:57 bappy-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jun 19 18:24:57 bappy-desktop systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 19 18:24:57 bappy-desktop systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

This is what line 140 of etc/apache2/apache2.conf says

```
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
```

Comment: The clues are in the text ... What does line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf say ? You probably have written something wrong around there. And what does the apache error log say ?

Comment: I didn't change anything. Must be the unnecessary files/folder cleaning app that I've ran yesterday that have cause it. There is no file in var/log/apache2. This is line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 

"IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load"

Comment: In my `apache2.conf` line 140 is the same as yours. There is only one line that ends in "tory": it is line 179 and it is a comment.  It looks like the file has been damaged, or was at the time of the error. You could retry that with `sudo apachectl configtest`.

Comment: Hmmm... things are getting too confusing for me. I'm reinstalling everything from scratch. Let's see if that helps. Many thanks for your efforts everyone.